# js-waypoints with animate.css fire too early somehow

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints, animate.css

Dear stackoverflowers,

somehow my waypoints fire when the page is loaded, not when they should fire. 
The goal of my waypoint is, that it should fire when it's in the viewport and 90% away from the top. Then it should remove the class 'hidden' and 'animate fadeInUp' (using animate.css).

Anybody with ideas for a solution?

---

**Here's the HTML it should trigger when scrolled into viewport and 90% far from the top:**

```
<div class="row hidden" id="waypoint">
```

That's the javascript I'm using, but currently fires automatically after the page loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#waypoint').waypoint(function() {
    $("#waypoint").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#waypoint").addClass("animated fadeInUp");
}, {
offset: '90%'
});
</script>
```

Here the links for the JS-Plugin and animate.css, I'm using.

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

http://daneden.me/animate/

---

Thanks to the one who's able to solve this little mystery.

Comment: Could you also show us the CSS for your various classes? Particularly interested in `hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it within:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#waypoint').waypoint(function() {
$("#waypoint").removeClass("hidden");
$("#waypoint").addClass("animated fadeInUp");
}, {
offset: '90%'
});

});
```